# Zend Controller fails to retrieve POST values from Zend Form in Chrome and Safari

Tags: forms, zend-framework, google-chrome, post

**EDIT: Resolved itself.  Recreated the `LoginController` and issue is gone.  Thanks for the responses!**

So I'm fairly new to Zend, so maybe I'm missing something blaringly simple.  The scenario is pretty straightforward.  I have a Zend_Form on `index` submit to `/login`, where I want to handle the username and password vars.  I use a custom decorator to setup the form, and the resulting HTML looks like so:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="/login">
    <div class="input-container" id="username-container">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" helper="formText">  
        <div class="input-overlay">Username/Email</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container" id="password-container">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" helper="formPassword">
        <div class="input-overlay">Password</div>
    </div>
    <div id="dropdown-checkbox-forgot-container">
        <div class="checkbox-container" id="checkbox-container-rememberMe">
            <input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value="0">
            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" value="1" checked="checked" helper="formCheckbox" text="Remember me" class="light">
            <div class="light checkbox-text" id="checkbox-text-rememberMe">Remember me</div>
        </div>
        <a href="/login/forgot" class="medium" id="dropdown-forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
    <input type="image" name="login" id="dropdown-login-submit" src="">
</form>
```

Great!  Let's submit it!  I put a simple `var_dump` in my LoginController to confirm that the values are transferred properly.  `var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost())`.  FF and IE both show the values as they are supposed to be.  However, Chrome and Safari do not show the `username` or `password` inputs.  There is only a `rememberMe` value in the POST array.  Strange...

Now I figure it might be Zend's accessing of the POST superglobal, so I change my code to `var_dump($_POST)`.  Same problem.  In frustration I tried `var_dump`ing both the $_POST and `$this->getRequest()->getPost()`....and it worked!?  It dumped one copy with only the `rememberMe` input and one copy with everything (`username` and `password` included).  No idea why or how that worked.  Any insight as to what the problem might be would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this the whole view script? chrome sometimes strips the form tag when not allowed (example: inside tables)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is not the whole view script, but I haven't used any tables in the rest of the script.  Everything is contained within divs.

Comment: There's no obvious problem with the HTML you posted. It might be worth running the whole page through a HTML validator just to ensure there aren't any broken tags confusing things. Otherwise if you are able to upload the page somewhere we might be able to spot something.

Comment: Hmm, alright I'll try to run it through the validator, though it seems like it is submitting the values fine, I just cannot access them.

Comment: If `var_dump($_POST)` didn't show the data then they aren't being submitted correctly, but I don't have an explanation as to why they are sometimes there and sometimes not. `getPost()` simply returns `$_POST`. ZF doesn't change this data.

Comment: You could also use the network tab of Chrome's developer tools window to see what data is being posted.

Comment: Fair enough, I figured as much.  I have now tried submitting my form to a different controller (`HowController` instead of `LoginController`) and it was able to pick up the POST on all browsers.  Perhaps there is a naming conflict with the LoginController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreated my LoginController through ZendTool and all worked as expected.